# How can I add a column that has value for some of the rows and leaves the rest of them empty

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like the following:
[image]

I would like to add a column (sentences) to this dataframe. As for the rows, I want it to say (e.g) sentence1 on row zero and for example sentence2 at row 6. So basically I want the sentence column to mark the beginning of every sentence in this dataframe. the sentences are separated by a space.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we will find indexes of the empty rows in the dataframe:

```
na_index = pd.isnull(df).any(1).nonzero()[0]
```

Now, we will create an empty np-array for a new column:

```
sentences = [None] * (shape(df)[0])
```

Now, we should set the first value in our array to become "Sentence1", and after that in a loop we can mark all other sentences:

```
sentences[0]='Sentence1'
index = 2
for a in na_index:
    sentences[a+1] = "Sentence "+str(index)
    index+=1
```

Finally, we need to add a new column to the dataframe:

```
df["Sentence#"]=sentences
```